# Lemmatization for Malayalam words

Tags: python, stemming, lemmatization

can anyone help me with implementing a python code to easily guess the right word (root word) from a stemmed MALAYALAM word?

Comment: By MALAYALAM word, do you mean the natural language or is this a strange data structures problem?

Comment: Malayalam is a language in India

Comment: Hi mate! I am also indian, and have you done some research? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please be more specific - write a question, give a piece of code of what you already tried and what you are stuck on